# Excel combo box

Tags: excel

I have a workbook that has a combo box list in it and works fine until I try to share
the book, then it stops working. I have since found out that this is how Excel is set up!

I have a validation list that works but will only show 8 lines whereas the combo will show all 22 lines at once, which is what I was trying to achieve.

Can I use a form control to work around this and if so how do I do it ?

Comment: Have you tried using an Active X Control Combo Box from the Developer tab under Insert? They have a Lot more options and allow for greater control.

Comment: yes i have when have tried that, i have a validation list lookup the same data and this will still work when shared.

Comment: can i add a sample worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested this, adding an ActiveX Combo-box to a sheet, linking it to a list of cells and sharing the workbook, the Combo-box drop down is unaffected.

If you are trying to insert a combo-box to an already shared workbook, then the insert menu will be greyed out, to do this you must open the workbook in exclusive mode by going to `Review` > `Share Workbook` and deselecting the share tick box.
Once you have it open in exclusive mode you can then add in the combo-box and re-share.